# How to fix ld: cannot find kernel.bin: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, ld, ubuntu-20.04

I'm trying to run an implementation of an operating system and I get this error when I run make on the terminal, I use ubuntu 20.04.

This is the makefile:

```
C_SOURCES = $(wildcard kernel/*.c drivers/*.c cpu/*.c libc/*.c)
HEADERS = $(wildcard kernel/*.h drivers/*.h cpu/*.h libc/*.h) 
# Nice syntax for file extension replacement
OBJ = ${C_SOURCES:.c=.o cpu/interrupt.o} 

# Change this if your cross-compiler is somewhere else
CC = /usr/local/i386elfgcc/bin/i386-elf-gcc
GDB = /usr/local/i386elfgcc/bin/i386-elf-gdb
# -g: Use debugging symbols in gcc
CFLAGS = -g -ffreestanding -Wall -Wextra -fno-exceptions -m32

# First rule is run by default
os-image.bin: boot/bootsect.bin kernel.bin
    cat $^ > os-image.bin

# '--oformat binary' deletes all symbols as a collateral, so we don't need
# to 'strip' them manually on this case
kernel.bin: boot/kernel_entry.o ${OBJ}
    ld -melf_i386 -o -no-PIE $@ -Ttext 0x1000 $^ --oformat binary

# Used for debugging purposes
kernel.elf: boot/kernel_entry.o ${OBJ}
    ld -melf_i386 -o -no-PIE $@ -Ttext 0x1000 $^ 

run: os-image.bin
    qemu-system-i386 -fda os-image.bin

# Open the connection to qemu and load our kernel-object file with symbols
debug: os-image.bin kernel.elf
    qemu-system-i386 -s -fda os-image.bin -d guest_errors,int &
    ${GDB} -ex "target remote localhost:1234" -ex "symbol-file kernel.elf"

# Generic rules for wildcards
# To make an object, always compile from its .c
%.o: %.c ${HEADERS}
    ${CC} ${CFLAGS} -c $< -o $@

%.o: %.asm
    nasm $< -f elf -o $@

%.bin: %.asm
    nasm $< -f bin -o $@

clean:
    rm -rf *.bin *.dis *.o os-image.bin *.elf
rm -rf kernel/*.o boot/*.bin drivers/*.o boot/*.o cpu/*.o libc/*.o
```

And this is the source for the code, I wasn't able to install the cross compiler that is in the tutorial. So I tried to change the makefile to work with the default gcc:

[source](https://github.com/cfenollosa/os-tutorial)

Comment: I think the file name is missing after the `-o`:  `ld -melf_i386 -o kernel.bin -no-PIE $@ -Ttext 0x1000 $^ --oformat binary`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You linker commands are buggy because you misplaced the `-no-PIE` option.

Instead of `ld -o -no-PIE $@`, write `ld -o $@ -no-PIE`:

```
kernel.bin: boot/kernel_entry.o ${OBJ}
    ld -melf_i386 -o $@ -no-PIE -Ttext 0x1000 $^ --oformat binary

kernel.elf: boot/kernel_entry.o ${OBJ}
    ld -melf_i386 -o $@ -no-PIE -Ttext 0x1000 $^
```

`$@` is the target of your make command (here `kernel.bin` and `kernel.elf`). Misplacing it like you did, you are instructing `ld` to output the result as a file named `-no-PIE` and to use `kernel.bin` (resp. `kernel.elf`) as an input. Hence the error message since the input does not exist yet.